# Visual Studio 2010 intellisense stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got a small problem with the VS2010. I installed Resharper and soon after my installation period has expired, My Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense stopped working. Its very hard to work without Intellisense. It doesn't even show the member properties even . I tried doing `devenv.exe /ResetSettings` and I end up with an error saying:

> it is not recognised as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

### My solution

I don't know how people are solving this but I just solved my above problem by resetting the Vs settings. Tools-->Import ExportSettings-->selecting the reset all settings and following the wizard .

By doing this of course I lost the little settings I made just like adding line numbers and stuff, but I did that again.

Not sure if this is the ideal solution for people looking for an answer, but just helped me to get the Intellisense in the first place which I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For risk of sounding like tech support:

Reboot your machine and check if Intellisense is back, else try `devenv /ResetSettings` again.

Comment: well, I din't reboot but I just reset the Vs settings and it worked. Thanks any ways

Comment: Worked by me, but I haven't rebooted my PC. Visual Studio restart, but it worked not immediately after restart, some times was needed for something (suppose to rebuild intellisence needed structures)

Comment: You should try the "Auto List Members" option first, see comment below.

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me.

http://miguelmoreno.net/post/Intellisense-not-working-in-Visual-Studio.aspx

[image]

In Visual Studio select Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages. Ensure that the checkboxes in the Statement Completion section are actively checked (not grayed out).

[image]

Comment: I recently tested JetBrains ReSharper and decided against it for now. After disabling it in the Tools | Option dialog, I lost automatic Intellisense.  This answer fixed my problem quickly and I didn't lose all my other VS settings as the accepted answer would likely cause.

Comment: Ali, you just use the image icon button in the editor to insert an image.  I'm not sure why, but image is not displaying in firefox.  it is showing in IE10  here's the image link http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAiAe.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I tried to reboot and devenv.exe /resetsettings.
What actually worked for me was the following:

1. Goto Tools > Options > Resharper
2. Suspend Resharper
3. Resume Resharper

No application restart or PC reboot or anything required after that.

Found here: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/11/09/resolving-issue-ldquoresharper-auto-completion-live-templates-and-intellisense-stop-working.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Saving my project then restarting VS worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally had two of the same file open in the IDE.  After closing one of them, intellisense started working again!  This is how you can reproduce it: 
Drag a tab onto your desktop, then open the same file by double clicking it in the Solution Explorer.  You now have 2 of the same thing open.  You can now drag that floating window back into the IDE as a tab and now you (unfortunately) have 2 of the same file open at the same time.  You can only edit the original one and the other one will drive you crazy.

Answer (score 1):

@Ronald McDonald, I tried that solution, but everytime I go back in, the Statement Completion options are reset, so that the boxes are filled, not checked (i.e. on for some languages, off for others). I'm guessing that it's ReSharper responsible?

For anyone else having this problem, if the above solutions don't work, and you have ReSharper, give [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/visual-studio/7/10354260/undo-does-not-work-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) a try:

Reset key mappings in Visual Studio: Make sure only one instance is running. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Reset.

Restore ReSharper keyboard shortcuts: ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> ReSharper keyboard shortcuts. Close Visual Studio.

It's too early to tell, but I think (hope) that this has worked for me. I keep losing not only Intellisense, but undo/redo stops working (even greys out in the Edit menu, until I reopen the menu a few times), along with copy/paste and most (sometimes all) Ctrl+ keyboard shortcuts. I've had this problem for years, on different computers, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to fix it. I really hope this one finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

First check in VS tools-> options-> editor -> statement completion is checked (not grayed out).

Then follow this procedure:

1. close all open files in the VS IDE.
2. Save & restart VS.
3. Make sure the file you are writing into is included in the project (and not excluded by mistake)
4. If this does not solve the problem, close VS & try from the command line running: devenv /ResetSettings
5. else try installing the hotFix: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the path location for the project . If it exist in some folder then place it into another.
This will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense stopped working. Tried the methods suggested here to no avail. Noticed it was only affecting only the current file. Closed Project, deleted the .suo file and restarted project. It is now working for all files. :)

Answer (score 0):

If using ReSharper:

- ReSharper / Options... / "Clear Caches".
- Quit and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had mistakenly uninstalled SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2.
Re-installed, then set Options->TextEditor->Advanced->Disable Database = False
worked for me.